# Map Oracle blob data to dataset direct

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, dataset

I have a table with a blob field that stores photos in jpg format.

Is there any way to direct fill the Dataset with the OracleDataAdapter?

Like:

My code in vb.net

```
Dim oAdp As OracleDataAdapter
Dim v_oDs As DsSubRegistro <- My Dataset

oAdp = New OracleDataAdapter(myConnection.sqlCmd("SELECT * FROM ..."))
With oAdp.TableMappings.Add(Common.DbDataAdapter.DefaultSourceTableName, v_oDs.Foto.TableName).ColumnMappings
    .Add("NU_ANO", "NU_ANO")
    .Add("NU_PID", "NU_PID")
    .Add("NU_RIC", "NU_RIC")
    .Add("NU_VIAS", "NU_VIAS")
    .Add("IM_FOTO", "IM_FOTO") <-- My blob field
End With
```

When I use the code above I get the error:
**Inconvertible type mismatch between SourceColumn 'IM_FOTO' of Byte[] and the DataColumn 'IM_FOTO' of Byte.**

v_oDs.**Foto**.TableName, Foto is my Datatable.

**IM_FOTO** on my dataset use **System.Byte DataType**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IM_FOTO on your dataset needs to be a byte array (`System.Byte()`) to hold the blob contents, but you only have it declared as a single Byte.

Comment: But VS2005 have System.Byte and System.SByte and I get error with both.

Comment: System.Byte is correct, but you need to declare it as an array: System.Byte(). Sorry, I used C# in my original response, I will fix that.